# Spring Data Jpa delete foreign key rows on delete mapping?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many, cascading-deletes

Here is my first entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;    

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    // Removed other stuff for brevity
}
```

Here is my second entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "membership")
public class Membership {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String membershipType;

    // Help here, I need another column called person_id which is what will correspond 
    // to persons or person rows from person table
}
```

Essentially in `person` table we will have `n` people(`n` rows). While in `membership` table for each person we can have 3-4 columns(depending on their `membershipType` since each person can have multiple memberships like primary, group, individual, secondary etc, pardon the business logic). So in reality `membership` table could have more than `n` rows.

Now I have couple of questions here

1. Would this be a `OneToMany` or `ManyToOne` from `person -> membership` table? I am guessing its `OneToMany` from `person -> membership table`.
2. How can I achieve this mapping in my jpa annotations and entity classes? I need this for delete operation i.e., if I delete a `membership row`, the corresponding `person row` should not get deleted. However if I delete `person row`, `ALL` corresponding `membership rows` should get deleted. How do I go about achieving this mapping and functionality?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `Person` - not person.id - to your `Membership`:

```
@ManyToOne
private Person person;
```

That will be read roughly as **'Many Membership can belong to One Person'**. If you delete one or more `Membership` it will not delete `Person`; it just will not have deleted memberships anymore.

In order to have all the `Memberships` of one `Person` to be deleted - when `Person` is deleted - add a list of memberships to `Person`:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="person") // maybe CascadeType.REMOVE is enough for you
private List<Membership> memberships = new ArrayList<>();
```

Actually without that you will not be able to delete any `Person` before you delete all its `Membership`s; latter has a foreign key constraint to `Person`.

That will be read roughly as **'One Person can have many Membership'**. If you delete `Person` also all its `Memberships` will also be deleted.

List is needed because that way JPA can cascade the delete to `Membership` for that there is  `CascadeType.ALL` (or remove).

Attribute `mappedBy` tells JPA to check field `person` to map to. If JPA cannot otherwise find field to map it will create a separate table for mapping.

Comment: 1.In `Membership` table will this create a column called `person`?

2. Should we do `new ArrayList<>();` right when we declare `List<Memberships> memberships`?

Comment: @theprogrammer 1. a column named `person_id` will be created referring to table `person` column `id`. 2. That is one way. But it can also be initialized just before 1st `Membership` is added to `Person`.  `EntityManager` initializes it automatically when it needs it but you of course can not add any `Membership` if it is `null`.

Comment: Oh ok thanks. One last doubt. In `@OneToMany` code that you gave, will it also create a new column in `Person` table? If so what name would it have for column?

Comment: @theprogrammer No it does not. This list is purely on the Java side. If there would be some column it could refer to only one `Membership`, right?